# Cordova Ionic framework select tag not behave as expected

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a mobile app using Cordova PhoneGap and Ionic framework

I have a problem in all select tags in the app only appear when run on Android 2.3 or earlier, the problem appear when user select an option from select tag, the selected value not appear in the select box, but it's value changed successfully i mean when i get the value of the select with ng-model it is work as expected

here is my HTML :

```
<select name='countryCode'   ng-model="val.countryCode" required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Country Code</option>
            <option >+2</option>
            <option >+3</option>
            <option >+4</option>
            <option >+5</option>
        </select>
```

when user select +4 as example the result is the following

[image: expected result is +4 not Country Code]

any suggestions please ?

i have tried the following jQuery:

```
  $('select').click(function () {
   $(this).focus();
  });
```

but has no effect .

thanks in advance

Comment: I also struggled with early Android versions on cordova (pure angularjs, no ionic framework). There were really strange behaviours from the Android side, like it didn't show a keyboard, or the keyboard won't go away after loosing focus... The build in browser used in that cordova seems to be a big piece of... poor written software. Finally we decided, to drop support for such versions, and only support 4.2+.

Comment: in your controller, put $scope.val.countryCode = 'THE VALUE YOU WANT TO BE DEFAULT SELECTED VALUE';